# How do I make Adobe Flash work with Firefox?

Tags: firefox-for-android, adobe-flash

I have Adobe Flash Player 10.3 and Firefox 5.0 installed on Android 2.2. However Flash animations seem not to work in Firefox, although they do in the Android default browser.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flash support was added in [Firefox 14.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/14.0beta/releasenotes/). Versions of Firefox Mobile earlier than 14 do not support Flash content at all.