# Flash is not working with Firefox on Android

Tags: firefox-for-android, adobe-flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make Adobe Flash work with Firefox?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11339/how-do-i-make-adobe-flash-work-with-firefox)

I installed Firefox on my android from the market app, then I installed flash from the market app, and Firefox still does not display flash on sites like charlierose.com for example.

Any idea what it is I need to do in order to get flash to work on Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current version of Firefox for Android does not support Flash content.  Mozilla developers [said](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/767909) that they are working on it, and eventually Flash will work in some future version.  No ETA was given though.